# Google maps - Get address

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Api: I have the objects like (sure just part of code...):

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
var result = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
```

I need to know the start and destination address(string format) of the route.

For instance I can get LatLng like:

```
result.routes[0].overview_path[0]
```

Comment: And you could get the last point like `result.routes[0].overview_path[result.routes[0].overview_path.length-1]`

Comment: Thanks duncan I will use it. But the question is how to get the Address(string)(Prague, Czech Republic for instance), not LatLng.

Comment: ah, sorry.  For that you probably want to use the `DirectionsLeg.start_address` and `end_address`, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs  So probably `result.routes[0].legs[0].start_address`  and `result.routes[0].legs[result.routes[0].legs.length-1].end_address`

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you probably want to use the `DirectionsLeg.start_address` and `DirectionsLeg.end_address` values.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs

So `result.routes[0].legs[0].start_address` for the *starting* address of the *first* leg of the directions route.

And `result.routes[0].legs[result.routes[0].legs.length-1].end_address`
for the *ending* address of the *last* leg of the directions route.